# How to make an AJAX call to a locally defined variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, dynatable

I'm trying generate a list after an obtained JSON, I found docs from dynatable library so they can populate a table in the ajax way receiving a JSON.

However, what if I already have the json stored in a variable. I've tried this so far:

```
var json = {
              "records": [
                {
                  "someAttribute": "I am record one",
                  "someOtherAttribute": "Fetched by AJAX"
                },
                {
                  "someAttribute": "I am record two",
                  "someOtherAttribute": "Cuz it's awesome"
                },
                {
                  "someAttribute": "I am record three",
                  "someOtherAttribute": "Yup, still AJAX"
                }
              ],
              "queryRecordCount": 3,
              "totalRecordCount": 3
            }

var table = $('#resultados').dynatable({
    dataset: {
        ajax: true,
        ajaxUrl: json,
        ajaxOnLoad: true,
        records: []
    }
})
```

So I'm getting a 404 code, I understand that's because that's not an actual route. But what can I do to tell library to request for that file. Isn't even ajax required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have it in a javascript array called `json`, you can (I make the assumption that you want to use `json.records`):

```
$('#resultados').dynatable({
  dataset: {
    records: json.records
  }
});
```

Comment: or `.dynatable({dataset:json})`

Comment: Thanks, it was my stupid not to read the docs properly: http://www.dynatable.com/#existing-json

Comment: Hello,
if I use capital letter in property names (e.g. SomeAttribute instead of someAttribute) dynatable shows values as "undefined": is this an issue, or is there some reason behind it?
JSON property names should be camelcase afaik, but that's just a convention - shouldn't I be able to use both PascalCase or camelCase names?